# MongoDb addToSet with DBRef array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following document

```
{
   "_id":"522f06a5396bc197c3e80097",
   "cutomers" : [
    DBRef("users", ObjectId("5d2f06a5396bc107c3580097"), "local"), 
    DBRef("users", ObjectId("5d2f06a5396bc107c3580099"), "local")
    ]
}
```

below is the query I'm using to update or add a customer into orders customers array using addtoset

```
cutomersArray = [{
                '$ref': 'users',
                '$id': "5d2f06a5396bc107c3580097",
                '$db': dbName
            },{
                '$ref': 'users',
                '$id': "5d2f06a5396bc107c3580098",
                '$db': dbName
}];

db.orders.update({
            _id: "522f06a5396bc197c3e80097"
        }, {
    $addToSet: {cutomers: {$each: cutomersArray}}
});
```

this query results in

```
{
  "_id":"522f06a5396bc197c3e80097",
  "cutomers" : [
    DBRef("users", ObjectId("5d2f06a5396bc107c3580097"), "local"),
    DBRef("users", ObjectId("5d2f06a5396bc107c3580097"), "local"),
    DBRef("users", ObjectId("5d2f06a5396bc107c3580098"), "local"), 
    DBRef("users", ObjectId("5d2f06a5396bc107c3580099"), "local")
    ]
}
```

whereas the expected is

```
{
  "_id":"522f06a5396bc197c3e80097",
  "cutomers" : [
    DBRef("users", ObjectId("5d2f06a5396bc107c3580097"), "local"),
    DBRef("users", ObjectId("5d2f06a5396bc107c3580098"), "local"), 
    DBRef("users", ObjectId("5d2f06a5396bc107c3580099"), "local")
    ]
}
```

cause addtoset always add unique values to array. Is there a way to insert unique **DBRefs** to array with `addToSet` without having duplicates.